# Bootstrap - Element background breaking out of container padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

as described in the title, I have a container with an element inside with a background colour that is breaking out of its parent. Hopefully the attached image will help someone debug this for me. The problem is with the brown line under the images [image]

Comment: add the same padding or margin to that block

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue, I had the background on the col-md-12 and it should have been on a seperate div inside that div.